# How to search the error code of 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio'?

Tags: avaudioengine, avaudiofile

Where could I get the information of `com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio` error codes, such as:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -50'

I always get an error while writing PCM buffer to `AVAudioFile`. The buffer comes from `AVAudioEngine`'s output node.

[image]

The error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -50'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x18eb46fe0 0x18d5a8538 0x18eb46eb4 0x1a8d051cc 0x1a8d731dc 0x1000d45e0 0x1000d4820 0x1a8d14654 0x1a8d146c0 0x1a8d8c26c 0x1a8d8c1fc 0x100ae5a10 0x100af1a84 0x100b001f8 0x100ae7a60 0x100af3128 0x100ae9634 0x100af5630 0x100af6f48 0x18dc0968c 0x18dc0959c 0x18dc06cb4)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4):

https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50

I found the link just now.
You can see all the error code of apple coding

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find the exact description of the error but it seems to be a generic **"invalid parameters"** exception.

In my case, and very likely in your case too, the issue was a mismatch between the **buffer** and the format of the **AVAudioFile** instance.

```
let settings: [String: Any] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44 * 1000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2
]

do {

    try avFile = AVAudioFile(forWriting: URLFor(filename: "test.caf"), settings: settings)

    avEngine.inputNode?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: avEngine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)) {
        buffer, time in

        do {
            try self.avFile?.write(from: buffer)
        }
        catch {
            // TODO
        }

    }

    try avEngine.start()

} catch  {
    // TODO
}
```

In the example below I was getting the **"-50"** error when I created the AVAudioFile in any format other than PCM, 2channel 44khz.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I was getting a com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio -50 error with mismatched sample rates.  I just had to set the AVAudioFile to match the mainMixerNode outputFormat.

```swift
let format = engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

self.musicTrackFinalOutputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: temporaryFileURL, settings:  [
    AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(value:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: format.channelCount,
    AVSampleRateKey : format.sampleRate
])
```